# How to update git folder in node_modules folder

Tags: git, github, npm

I have 0.0.1 version but want to update 0.0.1 version in my project's node_module folder. I don't want to change version but this is not my major request. I wish to update with npm command if I can't update 0.0.1 version with simple patch, and if there is only one way to do this by creating new version like 0.0.2, how can I do this with simple script?

for eg. `npm run updateGitAndNpm`

Comment: How about using the `npm update <package>` command? See [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update).

Comment: @MikeEason, npm-update : `This command will update all the packages listed to the latest version (specified by the tag config), respecting semver.` But I'm changing module in the another application node_modules folder(which are mine module and app). I wish to quick versioning and commiting to git and updating npm publish.